# I would like some help on how to align the name to the center of these images

Tags: html, css, alignment

Here is a fiddle i found that i would love to know how to align the "Name" to the center of the image... ive tried using width:100%; and left:0; / right:0; without sucess.. i only make it align to the center of all 3 images.

http://jsfiddle.net/25nsp/

HTML:

```
<div id="design-cast">
 <h4>Design</h4>

<div class="member">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OBUL7se.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="Responsive image" />
    <div class="name">Name
        <br />Description</div>
</div>
<div class="member">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OBUL7se.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="Responsive image" />
    <div class="name">Name
        <br />Description</div>
</div>
<div class="member">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/zmPeyso.png" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="Responsive image" />
    <div class="name">Name
        <br />Description</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.name {
    /* position: absolute; */*remove this line*/
    bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, please update your css code to this:

```
.name {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 31%;
}
```

Please look into bootstrap or a different grid system next time,
using `position: absolute;` in this scenario, is the devils work.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `.name` class as

```
.name {
    bottom:0px;
    text-align: center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.member {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.member .name {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="design-cast">
  <h4>Design</h4>
  <div class="member">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OBUL7se.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="Responsive image" />
    <div class="name">Name
      <br />Description</div>
  </div>
  <div class="member">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OBUL7se.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="Responsive image" />
    <div class="name">Name
      <br />Description</div>
  </div>
  <div class="member">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/zmPeyso.png" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="Responsive image" />
    <div class="name">Name
      <br />Description</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-align:center` CSS property. Following is the updated `name` class

```
.name {
    //position:absolute; // Remove this
    bottom:0px;
    text-align:center;
}
```